# How to print div contents keeping CSS

Tags: jquery, css, html, printing

I would like to print div contents while keeping the css applied on the div and it inner html.

Am using jQuery Print Element but its striping off the css.

Comment: any chance of you returning to this question?

Answer (score 7):

How about

```
function printDiv(id) {

  var html = "";

  $('link').each(function() { // find all <link tags that have
    if ($(this).attr('rel').indexOf('stylesheet') !=-1) { // rel="stylesheet"
      html += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+$(this).attr("href")+'" />';
    }
  });
  html += '<body onload="window.focus(); window.print()">+$("#"+id).html()+'</body>';
  var w = window.open("","print");
  if (w) { w.document.write(html); w.document.close() }

}
```

Comment: What is the "stylesheet" is it my stylesheet path?

Comment: And how do u call your function; $('#PrintinPopup').click(function(){
    printDiv("#print");
   });

Comment: Yes, but either remove your # or mine from here `+$("#"+id)`

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/jasonday/printThis

Plugin I authored for this exact scenario.

Comment: how can I use this plugin?

Comment: @Yasitha - Comments/usage are in the file itself in the github repo

Answer (score 0):

Use the .html() method.  It will grab all of the HTML inside of the selected element.

```
var myDivContents = $("div").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access all contents of your div with

```
var $contents = $( 'div' ).contents();
```

this includes all tags and also texts.

If you are only interested at the code you could use

```
var htmlContents = $( 'div' ).html();
```

this will give you the content as string.

To print out the code just insert it into another element

```
$( 'div.new' ).append( $contents );

$( 'div.new' ).html( htmlContents );
```

If some styles aren't applied, maybe they depend on the wraping elements and their classes, that's an important thing to grok.

Comment: Thanks but it still stripes off the css